# Break out of the flow of divs in HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got a rails app in which a container div sits in the application layout (around the yield tag).

What I'd like to know is whether it's possible to break out of the container div within the views if I'm using HAML.

In standard HTML I could just close off the div and with a cheeky  at the top of the view and the re-open it further down the code, but HAML's nesting doesn't allow this as the main container is set outside the views.

Any workarounds other than having to place the container into every view rather than in the main app layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filters](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters) :

In layout:

```
%div
  = yield
```

In template:

```
:plain
   </div>

# haml...

:plain
   <div>
```